# Make Username and Password input box with AppleScript

Tags: passwords, applescript, inputbox

I would like to make a dialog input box that looks exactly like this in AppleScript: [image]

Except without the picture in the top left of the lock.

Also, I need to be able to save both inputs.

I know I can use `tell application "System Events" to display dialog "blah blah" default answer "" end tell` but I can not find a way to have multiple and labeled fields.

Comment: Just an aside: the GUI commands are part of the _Standard Additions_ library, not System Events - no need for `tell application "System Events"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Natively, **AppleScript doesn't offer this capability as of OSX 10.10**.

**To see what GUI operations are supported**, check the `User Interaction` suite of the dictionary of the Standard Additions (`StandardAdditions.def`, accessible from `Script Editor.app` via `File > Open Dictionary... > StandardAdditions.osax`).

The **closest approximation is a *single* input-field dialog** - prompting for a password only - as follows (a limitation you've already noted in the question, but just to illustrate how to prompt for a *password* and how to use *custom buttons*):

```applescript
display dialog ¬
    "Installer is ..." default answer ¬
    "" buttons {"Cancel", "Install Software"} ¬
    default button 2 ¬
    with hidden answer
```

To get what you want, **you need a third-party library such as [Pashua](http://www.bluem.net/en/mac/pashua/)**.

Here's how you would define the requested dialog in Pashua and process the returned values:

```applescript
# Define the dialog using a textual definition similar to a properties file.
set dlgDef to "
# Window title (if you don't set one explicitly (even if empty), it'll be 'Pashua')
*.title = 

# Add the hint (static text).
st.type = text
st.text = Installer is trying to install new software. Type your password to allow this.

# Add the username field.
tfn.type = textfield
tfn.label = Name:

# Add the password field.
tfp.type = password
tfp.label = Password:

# Add the buttons.
cb.type = cancelbutton
db.type = defaultbutton
db.label = Install Software
"

# Show the dialog. 
# Return value is a record whose keys are the element names from the dialog
# definition (e.g., "tfn" for the  usernam text field) and whose
# values are the values entered (for input fields) or 
# whether a given button was clicked or not ("1" or "0")
set theResult to showDialog(dlgDef, "")

# Process the returned values.
if cb of theResult is "1" then
    display alert "User canceled the dialog."
else
    display alert "name=[" & tfn of theResult & "]; password=[" & tfp of theResult & "]"
end if
```

The dialog will look like this:

[image]

---

**Overview of setting up Pashua**

<sup>Note: This is a simplified overview; for full instructions, see `Read me.html` and `Documentation.html` in the downloaded disc image.</sup>

- Download and mount the disc image from http://www.bluem.net/en/mac/pashua/
- Place `Pashua.app` in `/Applications`, `~/Applications`, or - in a pinch - in the same folder as the invoking script.

  - `Pashua.app` is the application that renders the dialogs (while a dialog is up, the menu bar shows `Pashua`).
- Copy the bindings code (2 short handlers, `showDialog` and `getPashuaPath`) from `Examples/AppleScript/Pashua.scpt` into your script.

  - Note: Due to a bug as of this writing, you must apply a small correction to handler `getPashuaPath`: replace line `return (path to applications folder from system domain as text) & "Pashua.app"` with `return (path to applications folder from system domain as text) & "Pashua.app:"`.
  - Alternatively, get the latest bindings code directly from the GitHub repo: https://github.com/BlueM/Pashua-Binding-AppleScript